# How can I ignore a 'No tables found' error from pd.read_html?

Tags: python, html, pandas, web-scraping

**The problem**
I'm creating a high number of URLs from an API request call and then using these URLs in a loop to scrape some information on the FT website. The problem is that a small number of these URLs do not contain a HTML table so I get a `No tables found` error after calling `df_list = pd.read_html(html)`. Unfortunately after getting this error message the loop stops.

**What I would like**
I want to be able to ignore this error message if no tables are found and continue with the loop. Is there a way to do that? I'm new to python and pandas so would greatly appreciate your help!

**My code**

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json

# Get the information from SHaresight API
r = requests.get('https://api.sharesight.com/api/v3/custom_investments.json', headers=head)
# print(r)
j = r.json()

urls = []
# Generate urls from above API request
for p in j['custom_investments']:
    # print(p)
    url = 'https://markets.ft.com/data/funds/tearsheet/historical?s='+p['code']+':'+p['currency_code']
    urls.append(url)

dfs = []
# Create scraping loop for all urls
for url in urls:
    html = requests.get(url).content
    df_list = pd.read_html(html)
    df.insert(2, "id", ISIN)
    df=df.head(1)
    print (df)
    dfs.append(df)
```

Comment: You should work through a Python tutorial. Regarding exception handling there is e. g. https://www.w3schools.in/python-tutorial/exception-handling/ There is also an official [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/).

Comment: Thanks, in my case I added the following code:     `try:
        df_list = pd.read_html(html)
    except Exception:
        continue`  and this works for me

Answer (score 1):

Add a `try` and `except` block:

```
for url in urls:
    try:
        html = requests.get(url).content
        df_list = pd.read_html(html)
        df.insert(2, "id", ISIN)
        df=df.head(1)
        print (df)
        dfs.append(df)
    except Exception as e:
       print("skipping url do to an exception",e)
```

https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/exceptions.html